# Can a background script of a Firefox extension make a cross origin requests to a blob url in page context?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a content script injected into a page which gets a file from the user (from an input file dialog), and I want to access this file from background script context to do further processing.
I therefore generate a blob URL (`URL.createObjectURL(file)`) and send this to the background script. (I do not send the file object directly with the messaging API because this is not supported in Chromium browser, although this works fine in Firefox)

In the background script, I try to access the URL using the Fetch API. This results in an error in the `about:debugging` console, complaining about disallowed access from the background script domain to the page-context domain.

If have configured host permissions in my `manifest.json`. Accoring to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Host_permissions), setting host permissions for my extension allows

> XMLHttpRequest and fetch access to those origins without cross-origin restrictions (even for requests made from content scripts).

My assumption is that this also allows the background script to access the page origin, and therefore also the file object which I get from a `<input>` element in page context.

In Chrome, this approach works just fine.

Am I correct in my approach/interpretation? Or am I missing something related to cross-origin restrictions and is Chrome more lenient in this regard?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Firefox, try looking on its bugzilla site. I guess you could just send a File object in FF as a workaround?

Comment: @wOxxOm, Yes, I can make browser-specific sections in my code, but then I need to be sure that the above approach is correct and will keep working in Chrome in the future. I quickly glanced over Bugzilla already, but could not find anything, so thought asking here before starting to complain over there ;)

Comment: The approach is correct and the blob should be accessible to the background script regardless of whether it was created by the content script or by the page itself. Assuming the blob's object URL wasn't revoked.